# cq5 reverse replication example

Tags: java, replication, aem, author, publisher

I try to learn cq5 replication. My CQ version is 5.5

I make according cq5 version 5.5 documentation:[link](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/configuring_cq/replication.html)

In documentaion says to go to link

```
Navigate to the support page on the publish environment:
    http://localhost:4503/content/geometrixx/en/support.html
Scroll down to the Comments section.
Enter your Comment, Name and Email.
Post the comment.
```

I see this page but where are absent comment field:

[image]

Maybe somewhere exist example how to use reverse replication ?

How to configure reverse replication on custom project?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe's documentation lags the demo application a little bit.  From the Support page, follow the `Customer Satisfaction Survey` link and you will see a form with various comments boxes that you can fill in and post.

Answer (score 0):

You can test Reverse replication on following pages:

```
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/blog/2009/07/sales_volumes_increa.html
http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en/community.html
```

Make sure that Author & All Publish instances are up and running.